# How do I pretty-print Rust structures in GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb, rust, pretty-print

How do I pretty-print structures (specifically `Vec`s) in `rust-gdb` or plain `gdb`? Whenever I call `p some_vector` I get this result:

```
collections::vec::Vec<usize> = {buf = alloc::raw_vec::RawVec<usize> = {ptr = core::ptr::Unique<usize> = {pointer = core::nonzero::NonZero<*const usize> = {
    0x7ffff640d000}, _marker = core::marker::PhantomData<usize>}, cap = 16}, len = 10}
```

This is just unreadable. Is there any way to get a result showing the contents of the `Vec`? I am using Rust 1.12 and GDB 7.12.

Comment: In `rust-gdb` I'm getting things like `$1 = Vec<i32>(len: 2, cap: 2) = {1, 2}`. In `gdb` on the other hand, I'm getting something closer to what you have. Have you really tried `rust-gdb`?

Comment: @mcarton do your GDB / Rust versions match?

Comment: Slightly outdated gdb 7.11.1 & rust 1.12. But maybe there's been a regression at some point…

Comment: Well, after upgrading to gdb 7.12, I get exactly the same output as his with `gdb`, and still the nicer one with `rust-gdb`.

Comment: Make sure the `rust-gdb` pretty-printers are in fact installed, using `info pretty-printer`.

Comment: > rust-gdb -q
    (gdb) info pretty-printer
    global pretty-printers:
      builtin
        mpx_bound128

Comment: Rust 1.12.1 & gdb 7.12 here, getting data ugly-printed in `rust-gdb` (even though `info pretty-printer` lists `rust_pretty_printer_lookup_function`)...